# ActiveRecord querying multiple joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following models:

```
class Epic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :planograms
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class Planogram < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :epic
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :epics
end
```

There's also an `epics_users` table.
I can't figure out how to write an ActiveRecord query to get all Planograms for a specific user.  I tried the following:

```
Planogram.joins(:epic).where(:epics_users => {:user_id => 1})
```

and many other combinations but I'm not that experienced in ActiveRecord queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can relate users and planograms like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :epics
  has_many :planograms, :through => :epics
end
```

And get planograms of a particular user:

```
user.planograms
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the relation with User is through Epic. You can try this:

```
Planogram.joins(epic: :users).where(:epics_users => {:user_id => 1})
```

You can read more for ActiveRecord's joins method here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use [Arel](https://github.com/rails/arel). First get the arel tables of your models by doing the following:

```
planograms = Planogram.arel_table
epics = Epic.arel_table
```

then create your query as the following:

```
Planogram.joins(:epic).where(epics[:user_id].eq(USER_ID))
```